# How to understand Haskell function parameters

Tags: haskell, signature

In the following function definition:

```
app :: Application
app _ respond = do
    putStrLn "I've done some IO here"
    respond $ responseLBS
        status200
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
        "Hello, Web!"
```

Hello the app function doesn't seem to take arguments. Why in the above example there are two arguments?

Comment: It does `Application` is a type synonym for `Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`Application`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application) is a type *synonym*. It is defined as:

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

It is thus a function that takes a `Request`, and a function that maps an `Response` on an `IO ResponseReceived`, and then produces an `IO ResponseReceived`. Usually such functions produce a `Response` that is then post-processed by the response.